# Instead of dsplaying the whole WSDL file , is it possible to see the WSDL as per the Service ( Method name ) wise

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am using Apache CXF for developing Web services .
I have a Webservice implementation  class and interface , currently consisting of 4 services (Methods )

Please see the image below the  services it is currently consisting .

[image]

When i  give the below command  this way, it displays the Whole WSDL file .

http://localhost:8080/web-ws-1.0/services/MyWeb?wsdl

My question is , instead of dsplaying the whole WSDL file , is it possible to see the WSDL as per the Service ( Method name  ) wise ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is one Service (called `WebService`) with four Operations (`getData`, `getNews`, `EngineData`, `checkCalendar`). I'm probably stating the obvious but a WSDL is a definition for a (one) Service and its (one-to-many) Operations.

... there's some overlap with Web Service design and Object-Oriented design, but if you find the Operations on your Service are *completely* disparate it may make sense to define these as separate Services (each with one Operation). With your example you'd then - of course - get four separate WSDLs.